# How to Prevent simultaneous execution of applications

Tags: concurrency, execution

I am developing an win forms applications that parses the xml file with list of applications to be installed. The applications might be .vbs,.bat, .exe and so on. i am executing  each application on separate process and waiting for it to finish before executing the next one. But sometimes there is issue when the 2 processes  being installed simultaneously and this results in an error.

is there any way where i can determine if any other installation is going on before executing the new application. That way i can wait till the execution completes. 
sorry if this question is already answered, i could not find an appropriate answer. Appreciate your time, Thanks

Comment: can you show what you have done, and what your desired output is

Comment: need more information here

Comment: i was calling a .vbs from winforms application, in some cases the vbs would start some other process and return control to my application. hence the application would call next .vbs or .bat which might try to start some other installation, hence the error. found a workaround for this setting a completion command in the .vbs and waiting for it to finish, Thanks for the reply